# php write file and set permission

Tags: php, file-permissions

I'm trying to create a php file which I can edit straight away without manually set the permissions.

I'm trying this...

```
<?php

$var = '<?php $mycontent = new Content(); echo $mycontent->block($p_name);?>';

$myFile = "testFile.php";

$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w+') or die("can't open file");

$stringData = $var;

fwrite($fh, $stringData);

fclose($fh);

?>
```

...it creates the file, but when I try to edit the file in my IDE it won't let me of course. I have to manually set the permission of the file created. Is there any way I can create the file and have the permission already set?

Thanks in advance

Mauro

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can thanks to [PHP CHMOD](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

```
// Read and write for owner, read for everybody else
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0644);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, but when do I put it in my code? Sorry my ignorance! :]

Answer (score 5):

Since this aspect wasn't covered in previous answers I'll add it here:

`chmod()` will only take a path string as the 1st argument. So you cannot try to pass to resource that was open with `fopen()`, in this case `$fh`.

You need to `fclose()` the resource and then run `chmod()` with the file path. So a proper practice would be storing the filePath in a variable and using that variable when calling `fopen()` rather than passing it a direct string in the first argument.

In the case of the example code in the answer this would simply mean running `chmod($myfile, 0755)` (the permission code is only an example and be different of course.)

full code after corrections:

```
<?php

$var = '<?php $mycontent = new Content(); echo $mycontent->block($p_name);?>';

$myFile = "testFile.php";

$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w+') or die("can't open file");

$stringData = $var;

fwrite($fh, $stringData);

fclose($fh);


// Here comes the added chmod:
chmod($myFile, 0755);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Php has [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php), works just like the Linux version.